# Arduino Control 12V Lamp with Car Battery

Tags: transistors, batteries, current, lamp

I'm working on a small project to control a lamp with car battery and I found this circuit on Internet. [image: Circuit from internet]Now my car batter delivers 5 amperes and I would adapt this circuit to my needs. Is it possible? Can you help me? Thanks in advance ;) 
[image: Final circuit]

Comment: Your car battery can deliver several hundred amps - you probably need 200 Amps or so to crank the engine when starting.  The load you place on your circuit will only draw the current it requires.

Comment: @PeterBennett Thanks for your answer, I made the measuring when the engine was switched on, the load (the lamp) required 55/60W so I imagine that the current that requires is around 4.6 to 5 amps

Answer (score 1):

Tungsten or Halogen lamp? No not possible with your design, Surge current is 10x steady state.

Also R1 must be 10 to 20x the resistance of the load to permit Vce(sat) with Ic/Ib= 10 to 20 max.

Then Q1 emitter rises and reduces current and Q2 burns up, so R1 MUST be on the Q1 collector side.

These days it is simpler to use a fully protected automotive High Side smart MOSFET switch. There must be 10k different types now.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, alogen lamp, I suspected this problem in fact I preferred to ask, can you recommend a circuit with a MOSFET, please?

Comment: Do you intend to pulse it fast with 50A surge currents? then you need a 5A choke with one of these http://ca.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Switch-ICs/Power-Switch-ICs-Power-Distribution/_/N-7590i?Rl=7590iZgjdgz1Z1ya6udzZ1ypwfslSGT&Keyword=high+side+switches&FS=True. otherwise use a 10-15A relay.

Comment: Yes, I want to pulse it fast such as a LED with 5A current

Comment: good luck,  average current at half brightness will be  up to 10A

Comment: I thank you, you've been very kind. I'm comparing some products to get the most suitable one ;)

Comment: if you accept this solution pls indicate for the benefit of others

Comment: Yes, probably I will buy one component, make some try and I will make the circuit

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you want to switch a 12 V 5 A load controlled by a 5 V digital signal.

The circuit you show could be scaled up to such high current, but there are better ways.  As a quick sanity check on the existing circuit, figure the Q2 power transistor might be obtainable with a minimum gain of 20, and Q1 with 50.  Dividing the desired load current of 5 A by those gains results in 5 mA, which is the current the digital signal must source.  Many digital outputs can do that.

Working backwards from the 5 A output and figuring a gain of 20 for Q2, we get 250 mA for the base current of Q2.  R1 (in the original circuit) sets this current.  It will have about 4.3 V across it.  (4.3 V)/(250 mA) = 17.2 Ω.  The common value of 16 Ω would do it.

*However*, look at the power dissipation in Q1 and R1.  R1 of 16 Ω and 4.3 V across it will dissipate 1.2 W, so would need to be a "2 W" resistor.  The dissipation of Q1 is even worse.  With the car running and the 12 V battery really being at about 13.6 V, it has about 8.6 V across it.  That time the current thru it of 270 mA yields 2.3 W.  That will need a heat sink.  It may also be hard to find that kind of transistor with a minimum guaranteed gain of 50.

A much more efficient circuit would switch a FET with suitably low R<sub>DSON</sub>.  A N channel FET as low side switch will be easier to control.  At the low voltage of 12 V, you can even use FETs that can be driven directly from a 5 V digital logic signal.  Even if not, since you have 12 V available, it would be easy to use a FET driver.  That greatly increases the range of suitable FETs.  It will be easy to find one that has low enough R<sub>DSON</sub> to not need a heat sink, but has high enough voltage capability to not be bothered by the occasional 10s of volt spikes on the car power bus.